# how do I plot the following values

Tags: matlab

imagine t is in the xx's

```
         t: |0.2 |0.4 |0.6 |0.8 |1.0 |1.2 |1.4  |1.6 |1.8  |2.0
first function   |    |    |    |    |    |     |    |     |
         y1:|2.0 |1.7 |1.4 |1.2 |1   |0.8 |0.7  |0.6 |0.5  |0.4
second function  |    |    |    |    |    |     |    |     |
         y2:|3.0 |2.9 |2.8 |2.8 |2.8 |2.8 |2.8| |2.9 |2.9  |3
```

Imagine y1 and y2 are vectors with images from the two functions. How do I plot them in colours and with a certain pattern in the line?

Also how do I do two seperate graphs: one for y1 and another for y2 ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the `plot` command along with the `hold on` to have both plots on the same figure

```
figure
hold on
plot(t,y1,'ro-')
plot(t,y2,'g+:')
```

You may want to see other color, line styles and markers by reading the help on plot (`help plot`).

If you want two separate plots do:

```
figure
plot(t,y1,'ro-')
figure
plot(t,y2,'g+:')
```